# Operation take longer than expected in visual studio 2017 error

Tags: c++-cli

I am sure my code work 100% and Run which it window form that contain a button to choose a picture and show it in the ImageBox but something wrong happens. I don't know what's the reason, i'll show pic to clarify it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 c++

[image]

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    Stream^ myStream;
    OpenFileDialog^ openfiledialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
    PictureBox^ pctBox = gcnew PictureBox;

    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog()== System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
        {
            String^ strFileName = openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1->FileName;
            //MessageBox::Show(strFileName);
            pctBox->Load(strFileName);
            myStream->Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the very limited information provided, it looks like you are trying to load an image from a mapped network drive which is performing  badly. You can user perfmon to monitor your systems performance

Comment: my laptop core i7 2.9 3rd edition with ram 16G and ssd hard disk which it should be super fast + windows 10 OS .

Comment: The message you posted is complaining about your network not your local drive. If you use perfmon you will be able to see any issues , I would pay particular attention to any network mapped drives

Comment: how i solve it pls this issue cause me big issue and delay

Comment: please provide feedback on the advice you have been given and details of what you ahve done, you have been given enough advice to solve this

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code. This is a bug in Visual studio. Check this post out: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/397102/a-64-bit-debugging-operation-is-taking-longer-than-1.html